# Facing critical issue: Toggle image source inside Listview using ViewHolder Pattern

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-imageview

Inside my Listview's ListItem i have a multiple controls and one among them is imageview. My purpose is that user when clicks on that image, source should change to something else. I am implementing ViewHolder Pattern, and right now i am able to toggle the source on click. My current problem is that when i scroll down new views are getting created(re-used), and when i try to move Up again the listitem where i toggled the image are again getting created with default image source as my datasource LIST has remained same. Kindly help.

```
        private class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        //Activity context;
        public MyTextView HadithBook;
        public MyTextView HadithChapter;
        public MyTextView HadithText;
        public ImageView FavButton;
        public ImageView ShareButton;
        public EventHandler Handler;
        public MyTextView RowId;
        public MyTextView IsFavorite;
    }


        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {


        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.HadithListViewItem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder ();
            holder.HadithBook = convertView.FindViewById<MyTextView> (Resource.Id.HadithBook);
            holder.HadithChapter = convertView.FindViewById<MyTextView> (Resource.Id.HadithChapter);
            holder.HadithText = convertView.FindViewById<MyTextView> (Resource.Id.HadithText);
            holder.FavButton = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.favButton);
            holder.ShareButton = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.ShareButton);
            holder.IsFavorite = convertView.FindViewById<MyTextView> (Resource.Id.IsFavorite);
            holder.RowId = convertView.FindViewById<MyTextView> (Resource.Id.RowId);

            holder.Handler = (s, e) => FavoriteHandler (s, e, holder);

            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }

        if (holder == null) 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag;

            holder.FavButton.Click -= holder.Handler;
        }

        var item = items[position];

        holder.HadithBook.Text = item.BookName;
        holder.HadithChapter.Text = item.ChapterName + " - " + item.HadithID;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (keyword) & !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (keyword)) {
            holder.HadithText.TextFormatted = (Html.FromHtml (ReplaceEx ((item.HadithText).ToString (), keyword, "<font color='#ff9000'><b>" + keyword + "</b></font>")));
        } else {
            holder.HadithText.TextFormatted =Html.FromHtml(item.HadithText);
        }






        if (holder.FavButton.Tag.Equals(0)) 
        {
            holder.FavButton.Tag = 0;
            holder.FavButton.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_action_not_important);

        } else 
        {
            holder.FavButton.Tag = 1;
            holder.FavButton.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_action_important);
        }

        holder.FavButton.Click += holder.Handler;
        convertView.SetOnClickListener (null);

        return convertView;
        }


        void FavoriteHandler (object sender, EventArgs e, ViewHolder holder)
    {
        Database db = new Database ();
        if (holder.FavButton.Tag.Equals (0)) {
            holder.FavButton.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_action_important);
            holder.FavButton.Tag = 1;
            db.InsertQuery ("insert into favorite values ('" + holder.RowId + "');");

        } else if (holder.FavButton.Tag.Equals (1)) {
            holder.FavButton.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_action_not_important);
            holder.FavButton.Tag = 0;
            db.InsertQuery ("Delete from favorite where id ='" + holder.RowId + "';");
        }
        db = null;

    }
```

Comment: This is monodroid app. I mean Android app using C#. Sir, This is compiling very well with zero compilation errors.

Comment: Ok, fine, I will remove my comment so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trap nearly everyone falls into when learning how to implement adapters.

The problem is that you are storing data in the viewholder that is unique to the position.  For instance, you are reading from holder.FavButton.Tag before setting it with values, thus your current code expects that tag to retain data for you.

As you scroll through the listview, the views are recycled, and thus you are reading data from another position.  You cannot cache position-dependent-data in the view holder.  Instead its used to hold layout elements which are common to all positions (i.e. the view is covertable, hence the name "convertView" in the getView method).  You'll have to cache that data by other means, like a hashmap that caches your data by position.

Comment: Do you mean i should maintain a dictionary item or Hashtable to store data like.. dictionary<position,isFavourite>()

Comment: Then on my click event i should update this dictionary item accordingly and in my getview method i should check the corresponding value of that position in Dictionary Item. Is this the to go????

Comment: Cool.. Thanks a lot...one more question should i maintain Dictionary item for all ListItems or for only those where user clicks on toggle image, because my listview has around 3000 listitems.

Comment: If you expect only a small subset to be clicked, then only put favorites in the list, and make null mean not favorited.  Even if you commit all 3000 booleans, it isn't that big of a deal.  If these are from a local database, android can read a simple database very fast (flash memory), and can dynamically populate listviews in the getView method (or by custom asynchronous method if needed).

Comment: Actually i have sqlite database on android, and i am populating my listview with data from that database , first reading all data into List<HadithListItem> and then loading this data in listview using my adapter. if user changes favorite, i have to write that back to database. what is the best approach for this.

Comment: you seem to be loading your entire database into memory in List<..items> (text, favorites, etc), to populate the listview.  

As long as that remains, store your favorites there, to avoid the databse call.  But if you run into memory troubles down the road, consider dynamically loading the data into the listview.  This can also give faster startup times.